# affiliate linking from wordpress

Tags: permalinks

I maintain a blog with moderate visits.
I am now trying to place links to books (kindle, play store, ibooks) in mu blog. I am trying to earn money from the clicks/sell of the book.

I have searched a lot in net, but I am confused, as I dont have any idea how to do that.

I agree my question doesn't have any link to wordpress except my blog is hosted in wp. So, please, rather than negative voating, I will be grateful, if you tell me the proper site, and the how to achieve my goal.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a plugin ("AmazoLinkenator") that automatically adds your Amazon afilliate link to all Amazon links - overwriting any existing Amazon affiliate link that others might place in a comment. The techniques in there could be added to to do other affiliate places.

Found here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazolinkenator/  It has options to shorten via Bit.ly your links, so you can obfusticate your Amazon affiliate tag. (You'll need a Bit.ly key; instructions are on the plugin settings page.)

It works on all content when saved: pages, posts, comments. Since it is open-source, you could adjust the code for your needs (making a copy of the plugin and renaming it, so that any changes you make aren't overwritten by a plugin update).